# With React, clicking on a label is not changing the input type checkbox checked value. Why?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following render for a React.Component:

```
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id={`checkbox-${name}`}
      name={name}
      checked={checked}
      disabled={disabled}
      onChange={onChange}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onFocus={onFocus}
    />
    <label htmlFor={`checkbox-${name}`}>
      <image alt="Checkmark" src={checkmarkSvg} />
    </label>
  </div>
```

When I click the label, I see the checkbox input flash but not get selected... I need the formatting above as I'm hiding the input and using the label to render a custom css3 checkbox style.

Why isn't clicking the label checking the input type checkbox?

Comment: Please show us your onChange method

Comment: I don't have one, defaultProps are set to `  onChange: () => null,`

Comment: When I delete, onChange, onBlur and onFocus from the input above, the same issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't change is because you are setting its value `checked` to `checked` in your react component. However, what you are not doing is onChange of the component updating the value of `checked` so that the component reflects this. The input has a controlled state, which mean you have to control it. Below is an example of this implemented and used:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { checked: false };
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
onChange(e) {
  this.setState({ checked: e.target.checked });
}
render() {
  const { checked } = this.state;
  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id={`checkbox-${name}`}
      name={name}
      checked={checked}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  );
}
```